# Hidden paragraph mark removes heading from navigation pane

Tags: microsoft-word, navigation

For a report I have to make, there is the requirement that the 3rd heading  is an in-line heading, followed by normal text. This was quite easy, following [this guide](http://wordfaqs.mvps.org/RunInSidehead.htm). For me, using hidden paragraph marks worked. However, my third heading is now removed from the navigation pane. How can I have an in-line heading still show up in the navigation pane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the **Heading 3** paragraph style, click **Modify**, and then select **Frame** in the **Format** drop-down to put Heading 3 text into a frame. By default, the **Text wrapping** property will be set to **Around**, creating a run-in heading that shows up in the navigation pane and doesn't require hidden paragraph marks. You might have to adjust the style's paragraph settings (especially **Spacing: Before**, **Spacing: After**, and **Line spacing**) and/or the frame's position properties to make the text properly lined up with the text that wraps around it.

[image: Run-in heading]