# Creating a style without paragraph mark (no carriage return)

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I want to create a style that is inline with the rest of the text body.  So after the style, I don't want a carriage return.  So I want something like this

OBJECT Pumps and Motors

I want to create a style in All Caps for the word "Object" and the words "Pumps and Motors will remain in another style.  What I have now puts OBJECT on a separate line.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See, for example, https://superuser.com/questions/1146386/hidden-paragraph-mark-removes-heading-from-navigation-pane/. Depending on the version of Word that you're using, you can use either the instructions linked to in the other user's question or the answer that's offered. That answer has you redefine one of Word's built-in heading styles so that it's in a frame, but you can do the same thing for any built-in or custom paragraph style; and while you're doing that, you can also adjust the style's font settings so that the text is in all caps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom Character style and not a Paragraph style. Then when you select the word `object` in the sentence and apply the Character style, the word `object` becomes `OBJECT`.